# Xamarin Android (using binding library with native library)

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, okhttp

My Xamarin App uses a Binding library to use a native AAR - Android lib.
The binding library itself is really simple. It's only one class with one method
which requests a JSON-String. When I use a native android app, then it works.
But it's necessary to have a Xamarin Application with a native lib.

When I call my native library from Xamarin app it will
throw two different exceptions.

the native code looks like this,
the request is executed with the OKHttp-Library.

```
    String url = "https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();
    Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
    Response resp = call.execute();
    ResponseBody body = resp.body();
    return body.string();
```

NoClassDefFoundError
 Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
 Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;

I also tried to add the OKHttp-Jar file as EmbeddedReferenceJar,
but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help. 
It's very imported to me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried okhttp nuget package?

Comment: @sermet many thanks. It works. I could solve the issue by adding OKHttp3-Nuget to the Xamarin Android Project. ;)

Comment: @RonnyCSHARP Please do not forget to mark sermet's answer. it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried okhttp nuget package?

Comment: You can click the “✔” In the upper left corner of this answer to accept sermet's asnwer